# animation for the label that have content with length more than its own width

Tags: ios

Is there in ios something like android:ellipsize="marquee" like in android?
I need to make text scrolling animation for label but I didn't find a way for doing it.

**EDIT:**

@ Tomasz Wojtkowiak :
many thanks for your recommendations.

**PROBLEM:**

I have a label with a define width in pixels and the text that should be displayed in this label, and this text have for example double label width. I don't want to clip/wrap/trancate, I need to show the full message. In android for the TextView there is a tag android:ellipsize="marquee" and in the above described case the text in the label will be autoscrolled from left to write(some kind of animation).

How can I do the such behavior in ios?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should to improve your question like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Believe me, there is many iOS specialists, which have never use Android. They can't help you, because they don't know what is: `android:ellipsize="marquee"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try this [JHTickerView](https://github.com/jeffhodnett/JHTickerView).
It is an open source project.. It has custom UILabel (UITickerView) that has a property as you expect! that is the label will marquee the given text to the it.